# Securing ActionCable in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have played [David's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0WUjGkDFS0) repeatedly about ActionCable and still not see a way around this: to prevent someone from broadcasting a message from a browser's console.

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

 ...

 # This is being called without any securities, or checking.
 def speak(data)
 end

end
```

Now from a the browser console, anyone can send a message and I do not want that:

```
App.room.speak("I am God!");
```

Can someone please show me a complete guide for ActionCable? Is there a way to allow a certain user to a channel? What about the browser console? Am I missed something in David's video? My main concern is the sending of messages from the browser console as anyone can do that and that scares me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example on [actioncable authentication](https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples/blob/master/app/controllers/concerns/authentication.rb)

Comment: Great. Guess I need to write my own posting rule from there. So to sum up, I must write my own authentication rule in the `authentication.rb`

Comment: yes, just like any controller you need to add authentication rules.

Comment: Correct but that still leaves the sending of messages from the browser console. How to prevent that?

Comment: The console is acting on your behalf now ( ie: sending from console is equivalent to sending from the web app for that particular user ) so if you aren't logged in it won't send ( not authenticated ) and if you are logged in its the same as sending from your app as a certain user.